# Reversing of Words

Tags: code-golf, string, whitespace

Sona is in her house with her 10 year old daughter. She needs to go to school to bring back another child from school, as school is over at 2 pm. It's hot outside, so she wants to leave her younger child at home.

She gave a bunch of strings to her child to keep her busy while she is gone. She asked her to reverse the words in the string. There are lot of strings, so you need to help her daughter in solving this huge task.

So, given a string that contains words separated by single space, reverse the words in the string. You can assume that no leading or trailing spaces are there.

The string will only contain `[a-zA-z ]`, so you don't need to handle punctuation.

You will be given a string as an input, and you should output a string.

#### Sample Test Cases:

```
Input:
Man bites dog 

Output: 
dog bites Man


Input:
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

Output:
dog lazy the over jumps fox brown quick The


Input:
Hello world

Output:
world Hello
```

#### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: [Related.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/26931/8478)

Comment: Can we take the input as a list of words? (i.e. `['man', 'bites', 'dog']`)

Comment: Can the output have trailing whitespace?

Comment: misleading title, we're actually reversing a **sentence**, not the words...

Answer (score 11):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 7 bytes

```
O$^`\w+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@@@vEpcQU679/79vYp5CUmZJarFCSn46AA)

Match all words (`\w+`) sort them with sort key empty string (`O$`) which means they won't get sorted at all, and then reverse their order (`^`).

Comment: Never used Retina but why do you need the `0$`? Can't you just reverse it?

Comment: @RandomUser sort mode (`O`) is currently the only mode that has this reverse option.

Answer (score 10):

### Haskell, 21 bytes

```
unwords.reverse.words
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#@59mW5pXnl@UUqxXlFqWWlScqgfm/c9NzMxTsFUoKMrMK1FQUUhTUPJNzFNIyixJLVZIyU9X@g8A)

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 29 bytes

```python
print(*input().split()[::-1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#@19QlJlXoqGVmVdQWqKhqVdckJMJpKOtrHQNYzX///dNzFNIyixJLVZIyU8HAA)

Comment: What does the `*` do?

Comment: @OldBunny2800 [unpack the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-parameters)

Comment: Ahh. Makes sense.

Answer (score 8):

## Bash + common Linux utilities, 21

```
printf "$1 "|tac -s\
```

Leaves a trailing space in the output string - not sure if that's OK or not.

Comment: Congrats on 50k!! Your turn today :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6), 31 bytes

```js
s=>s.split` `.reverse().join` `
```

---

### Try it

```js
f=
s=>s.split` `.reverse().join` `
o.innerText=f(i.value="Man bites dog")
oninput=_=>o.innerText=f(i.value)
```

```html
<input id=i><pre id=o>
```

Comment: It's answers like this, that is essentially the same as my C# answer that makes me hate C# for golfing. All the extra fluff in my answer nearly doubles the byte count... +1

Comment: Side note: In C# if you pass nothing to `Split` it splits on whitespace by default, can you do the same here?

Comment: Unfortunately not, @TheLethalCoder, if you don't supply a string/regex to `split` in JS, it will either split on each individual character or create an array with a single element containing the original string, depending on the syntax used.

Answer (score 7):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 6 bytes

```
ṇ₁↔~ṇ₁
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@/9wZ/ujpsZHbVPqIKz//5V8E/MUkjJLUosVUvLTlf5HAQA)

#### Explanation

```
ṇ₁        Split on spaces
  ↔       Reverse
   ~ṇ₁    Join with spaces
```

Note that both "split on spaces" and "join wth spaces" use the same built-in, that is `ṇ₁`, just used in different "directions".

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
ḲṚK
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/9wx6aHO2d5////3zcxTyEpsyS1WCElPx0A)

Explanation:

```
Ḳ     Splits the input at spaces
Ṛ     Reverses the array
K     Joins the array, using spaces
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krk

Answer (score 6):

## R, 19 bytes

```
cat(rev(scan(,'')))
```

reads the string from stdin. By default, `scan` reads tokens separated by spaces/newlines, so it reads the words in as a vector. `rev` reverses, and `cat` prints the elements with spaces.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/r#@5@cWKJRlFqmUZycmKeho66uqan53zcxTyEpsyS1WCElP/0/AA)

Answer (score 4):

## C#, 58 bytes

```c#
using System.Linq;s=>string.Join(" ",s.Split().Reverse());
```

Answer (score 4):

## C, <s>54</s> 48 bytes

**Using arguments as input, 48 bytes**

```c
main(c,v)char**v;{while(--c)printf("%s ",v[c]);}
```

[*Try Online*](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#@5@bmJmnkaxTppmckVikpVVmXV2ekZmTqqGrm6xZUJSZV5KmoaRarKCkUxadHKtpXfv////cxLz/qYklxf9T8tMB)

```c
> ./a.out man bites dog
```

**Using pointers, 84 bytes**

```c
f(char*s){char*t=s;while(*t)t++;while(t-s){while(*t>32)t--;*t=0;printf("%s ",t+1);}}
```

*Use*

```c
main(){ f("man bites dog"); }
```

Comment: That's sneaky, using the shell to do the word-splitting for you!  Clever abuse of the rules.

Comment: Second one only works if your compiler puts strings into writable storage and has non-printing character immediately preceding.  It segfaults here.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
#Rðý
```

Note: Will only work for 2 or more words. +1 byte if this is not OK.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@68cdHjD4b3///sm5ikkZZakFiuk5KcDAA)

Comment: I see unicode, is it reallly 4 bytes?

Comment: Yes, 05AB1E uses a custom [codepage](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/docs/code-page.md)

Comment: `#R¸»` alternate 4-byte solution :P.

Answer (score 3):

## [GNU Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/), 62 bytes

```
$(if $1,$(call $0,$(wordlist 2,$(words $1),$1)) $(word 1,$1),)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/tio-transpilers), 74 bytes

```
,[>++++[<-------->-],]<[>++++[->--------<]+>[[<]>[+>]<]<-[<]>[.>]<[[-]<]<]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brainfuck#@68TbacNBNE2ulBgpxurE2sDFQXyoMAmVtsuOtom1i5a2y7WJtZGF8zWA7Kjo3VBArH//7vkpyskZZakFivkJuYBAA)

This code creates the number -32 in two different places, but that seems to be fewer bytes than trying to maintain a single -32.

#### Explanation

```
,[                        input first character
  >++++[<-------->-]      subtract 32 from current character (so space becomes zero)
,]                        repeat for all characters in input
<                         go to last character of last word
[                         while there are more words to display:
 >++++[->--------<]       create -32 two cells right of last letter
 +>                       increment trailing space cell (1 right of last letter) so the next loop works
 [[<]>[+>]<]              add 32 to all cells in word and trailing space cell
 <-                       subtract the previously added 1 from the trailing space
 [<]>                     move pointer to beginning of word
 [.>]<                    output word (with trailing space)
 [[-]<]                   erase word
 <                        move to last character of previous word
]
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 48 bytes

Almost gave up on this one, but finally got there.

```
oU_;SW;@?ABu>):tS-?;\0$q^s.$;;<$|1osU!(;;...<#(1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cubix#@58fGm8dHG7tYO/oVGqnaVUSrGtvHWOgUhhXrKdibW2jUmOYXxyqqGFtraenZ6OsYfj/f0lRfmlSTqpCRqpCZjEA)

This maps onto a cube with a side length of three as follows

```
      o U _
      ; S W
      ; @ ?
A B u > ) : t S - ? ; \
0 $ q ^ s . $ ; ; < $ |
1 o s U ! ( ; ; . . . <
      # ( 1
      . . .
      . . .
```

The general steps are:

- Get all input `A` and reverse `B` stack
- Move the negative `q` to the bottom, add a counter `0` to the stack. bit of jumping around in here.
- Find space/end loop, also puts stack in correct print order.

  - Increment counter `)` and fetch the counter item from the stack `t`
  - Is it a space or EOI `S-?`
  - Repeat if not
- Print word loop

  - Decrement counter `(`
  - Exit loop if counter `!U` is 0
  - Swap `s` counter with character on stack
  - Print `o` character and pop it from the stack `;`
  - Repeat loop
- Get the length of the stack `#` and decrement `(`
- Check `?` if 0 and exit `@` if it is 0
- Otherwise print a space `So` clean up `;;` and go back to the first loop.

I've skipped a number of superfluous steps, but you can see it [Step By Step](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=ICAgICAgbyBVIF8KICAgICAgOyBTIFcKICAgICAgOyBAID8KQSBCIHUgPiApIDogdCBTIC0gPyA7IFwKMCAkIHEgXiBzIC4gJCA7IDsgPCAkIHwKMSBvIHMgVSAhICggOyA7IC4gLiAuIDwKICAgICAgIyAoIDEKICAgICAgLiAuIC4KICAgICAgLiAuIC4K&input=aGVyZSB0aGV5IGFyZQ==&speed=10)

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>11</s> <s>10</s> <s>7</s> 4  bytes

My first attempt at Japt.

```
¸w ¸
```

[Try it online](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.4&code=uHcguA==&input=Ik1hbiBiaXRlcyBkb2ci)

- Saved 3 bytes thanks to [ETHproductions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42545/ethproductions)

---

### Explanation

```
    :Implicit input of string U
¸   :Split on <space>
w   :Reverse
¸   :Join with <space>
```

---

Please share your Japt tips [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/121253/58974).

Comment: Thanks for using Japt :-) You can use `¸` in place of `qS `, which should save you three bytes here. (See the "Unicode shortcuts" section of the interpreter docs)

Comment: Nice! you can save a byte if you use the [`-S` flag](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.4&code=uHc=&input=Ik1hbiBiaXRlcyBkb2ciLVM=).

Comment: I count 2 bytes, @obarakon. Unless the flag is included in the byte count, in which case that would be 4 byes, no?

Comment: @Shaggy Each flag counts as one byte. So `-S` would be +1 onto your total byte count.

Comment: Ah, I see. Is that a PPCG thing or a Japt thing?

Comment: @Shaggy It's a PPCG thing. [Source](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/274/61613)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 34 bytes

```python
lambda s:' '.join(s.split()[::-1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#S7ON@Z@TmJuUkqhQbKWuoK6XlZ@Zp1GsV1yQk1mioRltZaVrGKv5v6AoM69EIU1D3TcxTyEpsyS1WCElP11d8z8A)

Comment: Out-golfed. >_> Well... the other one only works in Python 3...

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 4 bytes

```
jd_c
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jd_c&input=%22Man%20bites%20dog%22&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22Man%20bites%20dog%22&debug=0)

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 47 Bytes

```php
<?=join(" ",array_reverse(explode(" ",$argn)));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#s7EvyCjgUkksSs@zVfJNzFNIyixJLVZIyU9Xsuayt/tvY2@blZ@Zp6GkoKSTWFSUWBlflFqWWlScqpFaUZCTn5IKlgHr19TUtP7/HwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Röda](https://github.com/fergusq/roda), <s>27</s> 25 bytes

*2 bytes saved thanks to @fergusq*

```
{[[split()|reverse]&" "]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/roda#S4v5Xx0dXVyQk1mioVlTlFqWWlScGqumpKAUW/s/NzEzr5orWslRIclZIcU1TcE9wzNLKbYmjav2PwA)

This function takes input from the input stream.

#### Explanation (outdated)

```
{[[(_/" ")()|reverse]&" "]}           /* Anonymous function */
   (_/" ")                            /* Pull a value from the stream and split it on spaces */
          ()                          /* Push all the values in the resulting array to the stream */
            |reverse                  /* And reverse it */
  [                 ]                 /* Wrap the result into an array*/
                     &" "             /* Concatenate each of the strings in the array with a space */
 [                       ]            /* And push this result to the output stream */
```

Comment: `split` uses space as the default separator, so `split()` is shorter than `(_/" ")()`.

Answer (score 2):

## k, 9 bytes

```
" "/|" "\
```

[Try it in your browser of the web variety!](http://johnearnest.github.io/ok/?run=%22%20%22%2F%7C%22%20%22%5C%22Man%20bites%20dog%22)

```
     " "\ /split on spaces
    |     /reverse
" "/      /join with spaces
```

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematica, 35 bytes

```
StringRiffle@Reverse@StringSplit@#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/mathics#S7P9H1xSlJmXHpSZlpaT6hCUWpZaVJzqABEMLsjJLIlW1lFSUIpV@x8AFCpRcEhzUPJNzFNIyixJLVZIyU9X@g8A)

Comment: `StringSplit[#]` splits on whitespace automatically, so you don't need to specify the `" "`.

Comment: correct! -5 bytes!

Comment: Ooh, and I think you can save another byte using function composition: `StringRiffle@*Reverse@*StringSplit` (call it like `StringRiffle@*Reverse@*StringSplit@"hello world"`)

Answer (score 2):

## [J-uby](http://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 23 bytes

```
:split|:reverse|~:*&' '
```

#### Explanation

```
:split   # split by spaces
|        # then
:reverse # reverse 
|        # then
~:*&' '  # join with spaces
```

Answer (score 2):

## Vim, 20 bytes

```
:s/ /\r/g|g/^/m0<cr>vGJ
```

This is shorter than the other vim answer.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@29VrK@gH1Okn16Trh@nn2vAVebu9f@/b2KeQlJmSWqxQkp@OgA)

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 3 bytes

```
_cw
```

My first Pyth answer, one byte shorter than @notjagan's answer!

Explained:

```
 cw # Split the input by space (same as Python's string.split())
_   # Reverses the array
    # Pyth prints implicitly.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 13 bytes

```sh
echo ${(Oa)@}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moVn9PzU5I19BpVrDP1HTofZ/LVeaQkhGqkJhaWZytkJSUX55nkJafoVCVmluQbFCfllqkUIJUDonsapSISU//T8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [TAESGL](https://github.com/tomdevs/taesgl), 7 bytes

```
ĴS)Ř)ĴS
```

[**Interpreter**](https://tomdevs.github.io/TAESGL/v/1.3.1/index.html?code=XHUwMTM0UylcdTAxNTgpXHUwMTM0Uw==&input=Ik1hbiBiaXRlcyBkb2ci)

**Explanation**

```
 ĴS)Ř)ĴS
AĴS)        implicit input "A" split at " "
    Ř)      reversed
      ĴS    joined with " "
```

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 7 bytes

```
qS/W%S*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@18YrB@uGqz1/79vYp5CUmZJarFCSn46AA)

**Explanation**

```
q        e# Read input
 S/      e# Split on spaces
   W%    e# Reverse
     S*  e# Join with spaces
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ohm](https://github.com/MiningPotatoes/Ohm), 4 bytes

```
z]Qù
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ohm#@18VG3h45///vol5CkmZJanFCin56QA)

**Explanation**

```
z     Split the input on spaces.
 ]    Dump it onto the stack.
  Q   Reverse the stack.
   ù  Join the stack with spaces. Implicit output.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 6 bytes

```
|.&.;:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/j#HYyxCsIwFEX3fsXFwVqoQddGRRHFQRdxlzZ9bQIxD5tXuvjvtTocuAcuZ6bSBtsCKXKsUEwsFY73/HoeP2qudDFmSSLmd9lo9Vwj1bcyoHJCETW3@oAKBjWh0RfynjFw52utH5Y6gosIjLKK7HshePdyAg4QOwmFViy4QYmhcyIUcAqtd9EiUpjUUJokZCxjh8W756lApbH7hUaTZf8NMeMX) This is reverse (`|.`) under (`&.`) words (`;:`). That is, split sentence into words, reverse it, and join the sentence again.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 62 bytes

```java
s->{String r="";for(String x:s.split(" "))r=x+" "+r;return r;}
```

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#NY4xDsIwDEV3TvGVqRGiByAqN4CFETGkaUCRQlrZLiqqevaSirBY39/283fRMuNsQ5p3QEji6WGdx2VrgatQSE@4qgjWJvvLLhcWK8HhgoQGKx9Oc9mhRinz6Ol/Mx255iEGqRSU1tRM@yz2ZMjLSAlkltVsxGFsYyYW8LsPHV45WOHc7rC6pPqw@Ffdj1IPeSQxVal2lTrbhDaIZ3T9M7/6ZV3WLw)

## Java 7, 77 bytes

```java
String c(String s){String r="";for(String x:s.split(" "))r=x+" "+r;return r;}
```

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#NY1BCoMwEEX3nuKTVYLgARo8giuXpYsYbQnEKDNjsYhntymkuwfv876PjhndUQEsToLH1QuF9ILXBdgchahVyj4X@pv9xg2vMYhWUMZQu9cZarI0yUYJZM8LWLch5m7Jv5cwYnYhlcj9AWd@90D/YZnmZtmkWbOSmLTXqnMJQ5CJMS6v/GLz9qzO6ws)

Answer (score 1):

## Gema, 29 characters

```
<W><s>=@set{o;$1 ${o;}}
\Z=$o
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ gema '<W><s>=@set{o;$1 ${o;}};\Z=$o' <<< 'Man bites dog'
dog bites Man
```

Answer (score 1):

## jq, 27 characters

(23 characters code + 4 characters command line options)

```
./" "|reverse|join(" ")
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ jq -Rr './" "|reverse|join(" ")' <<< 'Man bites dog'
dog bites Man
```

[On-line test](https://jqplay.org/s/34A0MMKVw9)

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 53 <s>57</s> bytes

Lambda + Stream API

```
s->Stream.of(s.split(" ")).reduce("",(a,b)->b+" "+a)
```

Following Selim suggestion, we just dropped 4 bytes

Comment: Save 4 bytes by using `Stream.of` instead of `Arrays.stream` :--)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 14 bytes

```perl6
{~[R,] .words}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#Ky1OVSgz00u25sqtVFBLzk9JVbD9X10XHaQTq6BXnl@UUlz7Xw8srldQWqKQll@kkJOZl1qsofnfNzFPISmzJLVYISU/HQA)

### Expanded:

```perl6
{              # lambda with implicit param $_

  ~            # stringify following (joins a list using spaces)

   [R,]        # reduce the following using the Reverse meta operator

        .words # call the words method on $_
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), 40 bytes

```
Fn.new{|a|a.split(" ")[-1..0].join(" ")}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky9KzftfllikkFaal6xgq/DfLU8vL7W8uiaxJlGvuCAns0RDSUFJM1rXUE/PIFYvKz8zDyxQ@z@4srgkNVevvCizJFUDpFsvOTEnR0MpIzUnJ1@hPL8oJ0VJU/M/AA)

### Explanation

```
Fn.new{|a|                             } // Anonymous function with the parameter a
          a.split(" ")                   // Split on spaces
                      [-1..0]            // Reverse the array
                             .join(" ")  // Join the array with spaces
```

Answer (score 1):

## [GNU sed 4.2.2](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 34 bytes

Score includes +1 for `-r` passed to GNU sed.

```
:
s/(\w*) ([^:]*)/\2:\1/
t
y/:/ /
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcqxDsIgFAXQna@4Y9vEvOjIF7i4uYkmraCiyKs8KtaPF43zOeJsrVoJNaZ0LZrdQe@7lsxKmyWprGbSBKp100cMPjuB5bPaXhwekz/eMCQuESd@4TrdRwE/XUL@cejf8/@uXQiMwinYD4/Zc5S6SF8)

Another answer, 38 bytes:

```
s/^/:/
:
s/:(.*) (.*)/\2 :\1/
t
s/://
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYoxDsIwEAR7v2JLggQnKP0CGjrKCCnBBgzGl/gcEng8B6GZYmbEO1WhI1ky1gjZxXpZYQbVW9h6Q6bMmkh13yS0oXiB44s5XD36IZzuaDOPCWeecBsenYCfPqP8cmzer/@78zEyRs7RfbgrgZPoKn8B)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
⌈ṘṄ
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E2%8C%88%E1%B9%98%E1%B9%84&inputs=%22This%20is%20a%20test%22&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `Ṡ`, 2 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Or
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#P2hlYWRlcj0mY29kZT1PciZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PVRoZSUyMHF1aWNrJTIwYnJvd24lMjBmb3glMjBqdW1wcyUyMG92ZXIlMjB0aGUlMjBsYXp5JTIwZG9nJmZsYWdzPSVFMSVCOSVBMA==)

##### Explanation

```python
    # Implicit input
O   # Split on spaces
 r  # Reverse
    # Join on spaces
    # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Cheddar](http://cheddar.vihan.org/), 26 bytes

3 bytes thanks to Conor O'Brien

```
@.split(" ").rev.join(" ")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cheddar#KyjKzCvR@O@gV1yQk1mioaSgpKlXlFqml5WfmQfm/dfUUPJNzFNIyixJLVZIyU8HCgEA)

Comment: [26 bytes](https://tio.run/nexus/cheddar#KyjKzCvR@O@gV1yQk1mioaSgpKlXlFqml5WfmQfm/dfUUPJNzFNIyixJLVZIyU8HCgEA)

Answer (score 0):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), <s>30</s> 28 bytes

```
{for(;++i<=NF;)s=$i" "s}$0=s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/awk#@1@dll@kYa2tnWlj6@dmrVlsq5KppKBUXKtiYFv8/79vYp5CUmZJarFCSn46AA)

Thanks, [manatwork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4198/manatwork), for catching my needless fluff. :)

Comment: Not specified by the challenge, but hopefully there is no need to handle empty input, so `{for(;++i<=NF;)s=$i" "s}$0=s`.

Comment: Trying to remember what was going on 21 hours ago... failing.  Good catch @manatwork .

Answer (score 0):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), <s>66</s> 42 bytes

```lua
for i=#...,1,-1 do
io.write(arg[i],' ')end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/lua#@5@WX6SQaausp6enY6ija6iQks@Vma9XXpRZkqqRWJQenRmro66grpmal/L////cxLz/SUCZ4v8p@ekA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 23+1 = 24 bytes bytes

Uses the `-p` flag.

```ruby
$_=$_.split.reverse*' '
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#U1YsKk2qVNAt@K8Sb6sSr1dckJNZoleUWpZaVJyqpa6g/v9/bmKeQmpiSbFCSn46AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Stacked](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/stacked), 17 bytes

```
' 'split rev' '#`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/stacked#U/dNzFNIyixJLVZIyU9X/6@uoF5ckJNZolCUWgZkKyf8zy8t@Q8A)

`` #` `` is "join".

Answer (score 0):

## MATL, 5 bytes

```
YbPZc
```

Try it at [MATL Online](https://matl.io/?code=YbPZc&inputs=%27Man+bites+dog%27&version=19.11.0)!

**Explanation**

```
    % Implicitly grab input as a string
Yb  % Split it on all of the spaces, yielding a cell array of words
P   % Flip this array
Zc  % Join these words back together with spaces
    % Implicitly display the result
```

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, 37 bytes

```
s=>s.split(" ").reverse.mkString(" ")
```

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/nexus/scala#JYpBCoMwEEX3nuKTVbLJAQoRegBXPUGso6RNx5AZRCg9e5S6erzHW8cXPRVDTAzalXgS3Ev5dsAWM@abfWhNvIT@ogtNQi9eSk5qDYzzlTaqQv7zvpZ/bUA5RTPb2ZohMsakJJjWxTjX/doB)

Answer (score 0):

## Vim, <strike>49</strike> 42 bytes

```
:s/.*/\=join(reverse(split(submatch(0))))/
```

Thank you to @manatwork for feedback

Comment: Does this require a specific version? Vim 8.0 gives me “E486: Pattern not found: \%V.*\%V.”

Comment: BTW, it seems to work fine without those `\%V` things: `:s/.*/\=join(reverse(split(submatch(0))))/`.

Comment: @manatwork it works for vim 8 only I did it with visual select aka %V for no practical reason.. my bad :D
Thank you for the feed back I will update the answer

Answer (score 0):

## **Ruby, <s>27</s> 24 bytes**

*thanks to @manatwork*

```
->a{a.split.reverse*" "}
```

Comment: Same with shorter syntax: `->a{a.split.reverse*" "}`

Answer (score 0):

## Swift, 116 bytes

```
var r:(String)->String={return $0.characters.split(separator:" ").map(String.init).reversed().joined(separator:" ")}
```

You can try it [here](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/591dbdd279c0f84b810b650c)

Answer (score 0):

## Clojure(script), 57 bytes

```
#(apply str(interpose" "(reverse(re-seq #"[a-zA-Z]+"%))))
```

Answer (score 0):

## tcl, 18

```
puts [lreverse $S]
```

## [demo](http://rextester.com/LVSED79262)

Answer (score 0):

## tcl, 11

```
lreverse ""
          ^
          |
          Put the string you want to test here between the ""
```

Can be tested on http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_tcl_online.php starting the tcl interpreter by typing `tclsh`. Then type

```
lreverse "Man bites dog"
```

%

```
lreverse "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
```

%

```
lreverse "Hello world"
```

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), <s>45</s> 29 bytes

```powershell
$args|%{$r=,$_+$r}
$r-join' '
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dck5FoMwDAXA3qf4hQgFcARukT6PRWaJg4jMlgBnN0w7o6ysvmXnskqUA9l8D1Ro449oJ81TeiWkpyHNeumGGHE4jXmQxbNlfOeueqNUWQdY2dDPn9FDFlZMd7vi/0MtTbgA)

*-16 bytes thanks to [mazzy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/80745/mazzy)!*

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DclLDoIwEADQPaeYkMHAgiYcgFu4M8bUMgW1Mjil8pOzV972DTyR@I6cKw0LRbT1FlPMc9Q1aml9oQyHflSq@mUb6gveyuq6F2nck@SEFs4dwSc8zAvuwlMPlmd4hvfggb8kMB7t9LpAw238Aw "PowerShell Core – Try It Online")? because there is the rule "The string will only contain [a-zA-z ]"

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dck5FoMwDAXA3qf4hQgFcARukT6PRWaJg4jMlgBnN0w7o6ysvmXnskqUA9l8D1Ro449oJ81TeiWkpyHNeumGGHE4jXmQxbNlfOeueqNUWQdY2dDPn9FDFlZMd7vi/0MtTbgA "PowerShell Core – Try It Online")?